# Accuracy of JavaFX Screen.getDPI() in AOT compiled code for iOS

Tags: ios, javafx, gluon-mobile

Screen.getDPI() is returning correct values on macOS on multiple monitors and builtin display, while both running on the JVM and AOT compiled with mvn gluonfx:build etc.

Once the app is built for iOS and installed, the value being returned by getDPI() on an iPad Pro is the same as the native height of the display, ie 1668, instead of the expected 264. This is with macOS 10.15, iOS 15.2, javafx 17.0.1, gluonfx plugin 1.0.11-SNAPSHOT which uses a tweaked substrate version to code sign using Xcode 12.

I've used the equivalent approach with some success considering OS idiosyncrasies in AWT/Swing to accurately size on screen paper sizes to provide a true WYSIWYG experience. Porting this app to JavaFX / glisten should I not expect this approach to work with iOS and GraalVM etc, or is this potentially a bug I should file?

Comment: OpenJFX has some limited support for the iOS [native screen](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/native-glass/ios/GlassScreen.m#L42). Gluon Attach has the [Display service](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/display/src/main/native/ios/Display.m#L82), with a little bit more information (like the notch). The main issue: I don't think iOS has API to find pixelsPerInch?

Comment: Agree José, Apple don't provide any sort of DPI in UIKit or other as far as I can see. I will need to take a different approach. Most articles refer to using the screen dimensions to lookup a static table of metrics - no future proofing possible here if I continue with the approach of rendering pages in actual size.

Comment: Yes, the lack of API doesn't help... Attach Display could have a dictionary like [this one](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo/blob/master/GBDeviceInfo/GBDeviceInfo_iOS.m#L158), but it will require yearly updates... or alternatively you could try adding directly the GBDeviceInfo framework to your project, but you still need to update it every now and then...

Comment: Great pointers again, I’d need to first figure out JNI and an Objective-C wrapper to GBDeviceInfo, which is another bunch of learning. I see Swift uses POSIX utsname structures, adding something like that to Attach Device could be more cross-platform and provide the needed hardware device models … again much more learning for me to contribute that!

Comment: Good idea, OpenJFX already uses `utsname` for [WebView](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.web/src/main/native/Source/WebKitLegacy/java/WebCoreSupport/WebPage.cpp#L696), and I just tested on my iPhone X, I get `name.sysname=Darwin` and `name.machine=iPhone10,6`. I'll file an issue to include it in Attach Device/Display.

Comment: I've taken a look at all the iOS resolutions and dpi, hoping that perhaps that all resolutions share a common dpi but they don't. The only way to be enable truly responsive views is by that dictionary, keyed on the name.machine, so adding that to Attach would be a significant value-add. Doesn't escape the need as you mention to continuously revisit that dictionary, and IMO maintaining it in JavaFX instead of a platform-specific implementation language has more potential to make cross-platform responsive UIs.